# How to get a pixel width from a span programmatically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do something like:

```
 $('<span>random text in here</span>').width()
```

But the width it's returning is 0. (The reason I'm trying to do this is to get the pixel width of a given text.)

How would I get this width, programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: The width is `0` because the span has no size. It has not been added to the DOM. Where it lies in the DOM will change its font-size, and is therefore impossible to calculate without rendering it in some way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to have it rendered.

You may do this :

```
var s = $('<span>random text in here</span>');
s.appendTo(document.body);
var w = s.width();
s.remove();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/aNJcA/)

Note that :

- nothing is displayed if you do this like I do in one go. For all practical purposes, nothing is inserted in the DOM,
- you could also use an in memory canvas but it wouldn't handle anything more complex than simple text and wouldn't take into account your span's css settings.

Here's the solution measuring the width of some text using an in memory canvas :

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
// set here c.font to adjust it to your need
var w = c.measureText('random text in here').width;
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/aUtba/)

I would use the first one in the general case but it might depend on *why* you want to measure the text.

Comment: I'd prefer not to insert anything to the DOM

Comment: If you remove it immediately, it won't be really displayed. The user can't see it.

Comment: @foreyez, you'd absolutely need to insert it into the DOM in some way. That does *not* mean it has to be visible.